# iOS ML Kit - Cannot install with cocapods

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I have pod version 1.5.2, the latest one, but I have problem to install ml kit from firebase, I get this:

```
   Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/MLVision":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/MLVision

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/MLVision`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.
```

Any solution?

Comment: Could you specify the Xcode version you are using? Also, is this a new project? Have you tried running `pod repo update` on your system as the log suggests?

Comment: XCode 9.2, I just found the solution by updating first: `brew install ruby` , 
`sudo gem install cocoapods` and then `pod repo update`. Thank you

Comment: What does your `Podfile` look like?

Comment: @EgzonArifi It would be better to write an answer so people can move on

Comment: I gave "pod repo update" only and it worked  ( I had the base cocoapods already installed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Solution in my case:

First try to:
`brew install ruby` , `sudo gem install` and then update the repo:

`pod repo update`

And that`s it, you will install ML Kit pods of Firebase

My Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'ML test' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for ML test
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/MLVision'

end
```

Comment: Following the instructions in the error message would have likely been sufficient.

Comment: not at all, it need first to update ruby. `brew install ruby` , `sudo gem install`